# What $X$ should be homeomorphic to?

Tags: general-topology

Consider $X = \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb C^3 \mid x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1 \}$.
I want to find a "known" space which is homeomorphic to $X$. A point in $X$ is two real vectors $a,b \in \mathbb R^3$ such that $\langle a,b \rangle = 0$ and $\sum a_i^2 = \sum b_i^2 + 1$. 
I don't see what can I say more about the last equation ... I know a similar space was a disk bundle over a $3$-sphere, maybe this is the same here ?

Comment: Is this not $S^5$?

Comment: Perhaps make the space a bit larger. Let the sum of the squares equal any $w\in\mathbb{R}$ to get $X\times\mathbb{R}$ and that leaves the inner product as the only restriction. Then for each $a\in\mathbb{R}^3$, $b$ must lie in a plane orthogonal to $a$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$.  That would be $X\times\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Ashwin: I'm assuming that the problem means for $t^2$ to denote the square, not the square magnitude.

Comment: @AshwinTrisal : Hurkyl is right, I consider the sum of square.

Comment: @John : I think your idea is good but how to get back $X$ ?

Comment: Aye, there's the rub. This suggests at most that it's a four dimensional manifold. It's been 40 years since I studied topology so I have only my intuition to rely on.  It would have to be by doing the reverse, in some way, of what was done by replacing the $1$ with a general $w\in\mathbb{R}$. One would have to "take back the $w$" somehow and replace it with the $1$.

Comment: I think this is clear that this is a $4$ manifold since we have one complex equation (or two independant reals equations which drops dimension by $2$). I don't think you can take the reverse, for example I think the topology of the real algebraic variety $\sum x_i^2 - \sum y_i^2 = w $ should not be the same if $w < 0$, $w=0$ or $w > 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, let us start analysing a simpler case: the curve $x^2+y^2=1$ in $\mathbb{C}^2$. Denote it by $X'$.

The projection $(x,y) \mapsto x$ gives a map $X' \to \mathbb{C}$. This is a double branched cover with two singular points of multiplicity two at $\pm1$. Roughly, this is because the the equation $y^2=1-x^2$ has exactly two complex solutions except when $1-x^2=0$, i.e. $x= \pm 1$.

Now, the  double branched cover of the plane at two points with multiplicity two is the cylinder $\mathbb{R} \times S^1$. This is basic cut and paste that if you are familiar with branched covers you already know. If you are not, read chapter 12 of Kauffman's book "On Knots".

Using the same trick for the curve $X$ (by considering the projection $(x,y,z) \mapsto (x,y)$) we get a double cover $X \to \mathbb{C^2}$ branching at the curve $x^2+y^2=1$. Thus, we can conclude that $X$ is the double branched cover of $\mathbb{R}^4$ branching at the cylinder. Now you can have fun with your cut and paste once again and completely understand this space.

Another possibility is to do a linear change of coordinates ($p \mapsto i \cdot p$) and consider the complex hypersurface with eqauation $x^2+y^2+z^2=-1$. Its projective closure is the curve 
$$\bar{X}: \ \ \ \ \ x^2+y^2+z^2+k^2=0\ \ \ \ \ \ \subset \mathbb{CP^3} \ , $$
and it is ismorphic to $\mathbb{CP}^1 \times\mathbb{CP}^1$. An explicit homeomorphism  $\mathbb{CP}^1 \times\mathbb{CP}^1 \to\bar{X}$ is given by:
$$f: \ ([a:b], [c:d]) \mapsto [ac:ad:bc:bd] \ . $$
Your original $X$ is the complement in $\bar{X}$ of the complex curve 
$C= \{ x^2+y^2+z^2=0 , \ k=0 \}$. Thus $X= \mathbb{CP}^1 \times\mathbb{CP}^1 - f^{-1}(C)$ and you can do the explicit computation.

Comment: Ok this looks cool. I did also use a covering (I also try to project on the $x$ coordinates, you get a fiber with base $\mathbb C$, generic fibers a conics, except two fibers which are double line) and arrived at the same conclusion at you but couldn't conclude any further. Thanks for all the computations !

Comment: And thanks for the reference this looks also really cool !

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Antonio Alfieri is really good but not explicit, and I found the answer so I'm just writing in case someone else is also looking for it : $X$ is homeomorphic to the tangent bundle of $S^3$.